# How do I disable Alt+Click to download in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, download

I'm using Firefox 7.1. As some of you may know, <kbd>alt</kbd> is used to highlight links without following or dragging them. But it interferes with the "alt+click to download" behavior.

I tried setting `Browser.download.saveLinkAsFilenameTimeout` to `100`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 13 introduced the `browser.altClickSave` preference in `about:config` to enable or disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> download behavior. On new profiles, this is disabled by default. If you upgraded, you may have to manually set this preference to **false**.

***Note:*** As always with `about:config`, a browser restart may be required for changes to take effect.